# Book or novella, set on an underground river on another planet. Social commentary

Tags: story-identification

Years ago I read a book or story that was about a scientist traveling down an underground river.  He encounters an alien culture and travels with a sage or mentor who constantly talks about how people should treat other people with respect and it all sounds very utopian and enlightened.  The punchline was when the scientist realizes that his noble sage considers anyone outside of his little village to be "not people" and they can be exploited or abused just as badly as humans have treated other humans throughout history.  There was a lot of stuff going on about Earth, possibly involving pollution and a dropping birth rate, but my recollection is hazy.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Please see our [guide to asking a good story ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31936). In particular, be more specific about how many years ago it was.